# Multiple Domains on Apache windows

Tags: windows, virtualhost, apache-2.4

[From stackoverflow]

so I have my website [www.example.net] and [www.example.com] I'm running windows, and I installed it myself, without xampp or whatever. I also installed php alongside.

My domain example.com directs to the .net domain. .com is hosted by name.com | .net hosted by cosmotown directed to cloudflare binded to the my router's external ip [xx.xx.xx.xx]

And my htdocs is C:\Apache24\htdocs (where my files are)

I want to have example.net be my normal site with my normal stuff and then have test.example.net be a secondary htdocs folder, where I can put certain files in it.

I've tried multiple times to make a virtualhost and things, but it either works from the main domain [www.example.net], but not from localhost, or my router ip. (It returns You don't have permission to access / on this server. [403])

I want my secondary htdocs to be just like the first one but a different name.

I've tried this so far:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Apache24\htdocs"
    ServerName www.example.net
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Apache24\htdocs_2"
    ServerName test.jackzcraft.net
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Check the Apache error log for relevant messages, please. A 403 error might be as simple as a missing index.html for instance, but the log will tell.

Comment: @HBruijn well now it's a 500 internal server error. i just copied the question from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32031588/multiple-domains-on-apache-windows

Comment: Adding to the 500 error, the error log doesn't say much. ill check later, but the main server [www.example.net] works fine.